# mongo db error - SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

when i try to run this command on cmd.

```
mongo test --eval 'db.testcollection.find({ createdate: {$gte: ISODate("2020-07-28 10:08:37.579Z"),$lt: ISODate("2020-08-04 13:42:40.975Z")}}, {place:1, _id:0}).forEach(function(x) { print(x.place); })'
```

it throws this error

```
MongoDB server version: 4.0.5
2020-08-06T13:33:49.336+0530 E QUERY    [js] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell eval):1:19
```

i try to add a semicolon at the end. it still throws same error.

```
mongo test --eval 'db.testcollection.find({ createdate: {$gte: ISODate("2020-07-28 10:08:37.579Z"),$lt: ISODate("2020-08-04 13:42:40.975Z")}}, {place:1, _id:0}).forEach(function(x) { print(x.place); });'
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is at line 1, column 19. So placing `;` at the end will not solve the issue.

Could you use

```
mongo --eval 'db.testcollection.find({ createdate: {$gte: ISODate("2020-07-28 10:08:37.579Z"),$lt: ISODate("2020-08-04 13:42:40.975Z")}}, {place:1, _id:0}).forEach(function(x) { print(x.place); })' test
```

`test` is the db name where `testcollection` is present.

Comment: No. its not working "MongoDB shell version v4.0.5
exception: Database name cannot have reserved characters for mongodb:// URL: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/createdate%3A"